# swagger "Response validation failed: value expected to be an array/object but is not"

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I am trying to get the "out of the box" hello world project generated by `swagger project create` to return an xml response instead of json.  Here are the steps I've taken:

1)  ran `swagger project create` and chose the express option.

2)  opened swagger.yaml and made the following change:

```
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/xml
```

Here is the entire swagger.yaml, if you're interested:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/xml
paths:
  /hello:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: hello_world
    get:
      description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: hello
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/HelloWorldResponse"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  HelloWorldResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

3)  opened the hello_world.js controller and changed the res object to not be json and set the type to `application/xml`.  I also added jstoxml to the project to turn the object into xml.  Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
const { toXML } = require('jstoxml');

module.exports = {
  hello: hello
};

function hello(req, res) {
  // variables defined in the Swagger document can be referenced using req.swagger.params.{parameter_name}
  var name = req.swagger.params.name.value || 'stranger';
  var hello = {message: 'hello'};
  var xml = toXML(hello);
  res.type('application/xml');
  res.end(xml);
}
```

4)  ran `swagger project start` and then ran the following curl request:

`curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:10010/hello?name=Scott" -H "accept: application/xml"`

5)  Got the following response:

`{"message":"Response validation failed: value expected to be an array/object but is not","failedValidation":true,"originalResponse":"<message>hello</message>"}`

The server outputs the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Response validation failed: value expected to be an array/object but is not
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at validateValue (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-validator.js:125:20)
    at ServerResponse.res.end (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-validator.js:252:9)
    at hello (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/api/controllers/hello_world.js:45:7)
    at swaggerRouter (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-router.js:407:20)
    at swagger_router (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/fittings/swagger_router.js:31:5)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/node_modules/bagpipes/lib/bagpipes.js:171:7)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at Runner.runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at Runner.pipeline (/Users/seanroberts/projects/hello-xml/node_modules/pipeworks/pipeworks.js:72:17)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the validation part in swagger.yaml:

```
definitions:
  HelloWorldResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

and put like this:

```
definitions:
  HelloWorldResponse:
    type: string
```

Comment: Well, that works, but is there no way to have xml *with* response validation?